# How to upgrade android sdk version in a development board?

Tags: android, sdk, upgrade

I am a newbie to android here.

I am using a development-board called hikey 970 with an android installed on it when it was delivered to my company.

Currently, I am running `nnapi` benchmark on android with `tflite` which needs `getprop ro.build.version.sdk >= 27` when I read the relevant code (code is included below). However, the board only offers `getprop ro.build.version.release = P` and `getprop ro.build.version.sdk = 26`. It looks weird because android P usually delivers a higher version of SDK.

Therefore, my question is that how can I upgrade the sdk version in the development-board? Do I need to recompile the whole OS or just need to download a binary and stuff? I have read a bunch of articles and they are all talking about `sdkmanager` which is off the point here to my limited knowledge.

```
#ifdef __ANDROID__
int32_t GetAndroidSdkVersion() {
  const char* sdkProp = "ro.build.version.sdk";
  char sdkVersion[PROP_VALUE_MAX];
  int length = __system_property_get(sdkProp, sdkVersion);
  if (length != 0) {
    int32_t result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
      int digit = sdkVersion[i] - '0';
      if (digit < 0 || digit > 9) {
        // Non-numeric SDK version, assume it's higher than expected;
        return 0xffff;
      }
      result = result * 10 + digit;
    }
    // TODO(levp): remove once SDK gets updated to 29th level
    // Upgrade SDK version for pre-release Q to be able to test functionality
    // available from SDK level 29.
    if (result == 28) {
      char versionCodename[PROP_VALUE_MAX];
      const char* versionCodenameProp = "ro.build.version.codename";
      length = __system_property_get(versionCodenameProp, versionCodename);
      if (length != 0) {
        if (versionCodename[0] == 'Q') {
          return 29;
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
  return 0;
}
#endif  // __ANDROID__

// ==============================================
// const NnApi LoadNnApi();
// Most of the function is ommitted.
#ifdef __ANDROID__
  nnapi.android_sdk_version = GetAndroidSdkVersion();
  if (nnapi.android_sdk_version < 27) {
    NNAPI_LOG("nnapi error: requires android sdk version to be at least %d",
              27);
    nnapi.nnapi_exists = false;
    return nnapi;
  }
#endif  // __ANDROID__
```

Comment: i see a problem in your code

Comment: Please say the problem rather than say there is a problem. The code is from tflite.

Comment: the problem is being able to upgrade the android sdk in the development board